# When to choose the null or column space to check a subset is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

In the Georgia Tech Interactive Linear Algebra course, two examples are given for testing if a "subset [is] a subspace". In [the first example](https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/subspaces.html#specialcase-22) the set is expressed as the null space, in the second it is expressed as the column space. I'm struggling to see why each was chosen for the respective example. Why not just use either the null space, or column space and not the other one?

Example 1:

> $ V=\left\{
>   \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}
>     \in \mathbb{R}^2 
>   \,\middle|\,
>   2a = 3b
> \right\}
> $
>
> The subset $V$ is exactly the solution set of the homogeneous equation $2x-3y=0$. Therefore,
>
> $ V= \operatorname{Nul}{
>   \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -3 \end{pmatrix}
> }
> $
>
> ...
>
> hence $\left\{ \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 3/2 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right) \right\}$ spans $V$.

Example 2 (hidden below [the first example](https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/subspaces.html#specialcase-22)):

> $ V=\left\{
>   \begin{pmatrix} 2x+y \\ x-y \\ 3x-2y \end{pmatrix}
>   \,\middle|\,
>   x, y \in \mathbb{R}
> \right\}
> $
>
> Since
>
> $ \begin{pmatrix} 2x+y \\ x-y \\ 3x-2y \end{pmatrix}
> = x \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}
> + y \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}
> $
>
> we notice that $V$ is exactly:
>
> $ V = \operatorname{Span}{
> \left\{
>   \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix},
>   \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}
> \right\}
> }$
>
> hence
>
> $ V = \operatorname{Col}{
>   \begin{pmatrix} 2&1 \\ 1&-1 \\ 3&-2 \end{pmatrix}
> }$.

I understand how $\operatorname{Nul}{\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 2 & -3 \end{smallmatrix}\right) }$ leads to the spanning set $\left\{ \left( \begin{smallmatrix} {}^{3}\!/_{2} \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right) \right\}$, and how the parametric vector form of $ \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 2x+y \\ x-y \\ 3x-2y \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ leads to $ V = \operatorname{Col}{
  \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 2&1 \\ 1&-1 \\ 3&-2 \end{smallmatrix} \right)
}$, but it's the initial step in each case that I am missing the intuition for. Why in the first case express the equation and jump to using the null space to show the set is a subspace, but in the second express the parametric vector form and jump to the using column space to show the set is a subspace? Could each example be tested using the other space instead (suggesting it was just for the purposes of illustration) or is that the only way of testing the respective case?

For example, with

$ V=\left\{
  \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}
    \in \mathbb{R}^2 
  \,\middle|\,
  2a = 3b
\right\}
$

I can see that

$
\begin{align}
2a&=3b \\
a&={}^{3}\!/_{2}b
\end{align}
$

and so (is this right, or does it change the set?)

$ V=\left\{
  \begin{pmatrix} {}^{3}\!/_{2}b \\ b \end{pmatrix}
  \,\middle|\,
  b \in \mathbb{R}
\right\}
$

Since

$
\begin{pmatrix} {}^{3}\!/_{2}b \\ b \end{pmatrix}
= b \begin{pmatrix} {}^{3}\!/_{2} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$

So

$
\begin{align}
V&=\operatorname{Span}{
\left\{
  \begin{pmatrix} {}^{3}\!/_{2} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\right\}
} \\
&=\operatorname{Col}{
  \begin{pmatrix} {}^{3}\!/_{2} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
}
\end{align}
$

(I got slightly lost on testing the second one using the null space, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a neat little way of establishing subspaces of vector spaces: prove that the fundamental subspaces of a matrix are indeed subspaces, then establish questionable sets as one of these fundamental subspaces of a matrix that you construct.

That said, as neat as it is, I wouldn't use this technique when starting out in linear algebra. I think it's better to get a feel for the axioms of closure under addition and closure under scalar multiplication. Using matrices like this means that your ability to prove subspaces is going to be tied only to $\Bbb{R}^n$ or $\Bbb{C}^n$, and this technique is useless for disproving a subspace.

Anyway, the first example is presented as a nullspace because the set is of the form:
$$\left\{\text{General }v \in \Bbb{R}^n \mid \text{Some condition that } v \text{ must satisfy}\right\}.$$
That is, the vector to the left of the $|$ is a perfectly general vector in $\Bbb{R}^n$, while the condition on the right limits which vectors we consider.

The second example is of a different form:
$$\left\{\text{Parametric form of some vector in } \Bbb{R}^n \mid \text{General parameters in } \Bbb{R}\right\}.$$
That is, all the specificity happens to the left of the $|$ involving parameters like $x$ and $y$, while to the right, we simply point out that $x$ and $y$ are general real numbers. Subspaces presented in this form are usually better expressed as a columnspace.

Just think about how you'd express nullspaces and columnspaces naturally. The nullspace of a matrix takes the first form: $\{v \in \Bbb{R}^n \mid Av = 0\}$, while the columnspace turns into the span of some column vectors, which easily turns into a parametric form. This will produce a set that is in the second form.

As you've noted, it's perfectly possible to change from one form to the other. In particular,
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} \in \Bbb{R}^2 \, \middle| \, 2a = 3b \right\} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} \frac{3}{2}x \\ x \end{pmatrix} \in \Bbb{R}^2 \, \middle| \, x \in \Bbb{R} \right\}.$$
This subspace can be expressed both as a nullspace or as a columnspace. The question is, which one is less work to do, and the above rule of thumb might help you decide.

(By the by, the method of writing the set as a nullspace or columnspace does generalise to more general vector spaces. Instead of matrices though, you would be considering linear maps, and instead of columnspaces of matrices, you'd be considering the ranges of linear maps.)

Comment: Thank you! That is a wonderfully clear explanation. I'm happy with the axioms of closure and non-emptiness - I haven't tripped up on them yet, at least - but it's good to know that they are worth focusing on. Your two rules of thumb for when to apply either technique make sense and much more clearly express what I was starting to understand (particularly the part about the natural expression of each space). I still haven't managed to change the second example to a null space form yet, though.

Comment: You could take the cross product of the two vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\-2\end{pmatrix}$ to get a vector perpendicular to both of them. Express this vector as a row vector (a $1 \times 3$ matrix), and your space will be the nullspace of this matrix.